# Statements after return

Tags: android, return

Hi guys this question may look to be very silly. But still i have to know the answers for this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
{
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);


    while (true)
    {
      return;
      Toast.makeText(this, "GPS Tracker running in the background", 0).show();
    }
}
```

in the above code is there any change for the toast to be shown. To my knowledge i dont thing it so. But i saw such a code being created when i view the .class file using jd-gui-0.3.3.linux.i686. 
Can anybody clarify it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statements that are after a return have a well defined name, in Java.  Such statements are "Unreachable Code".  It is impossible for code (that is in the same scope as the return in question) to execute after a return executes with one exception; code in a finally block will execute.  Here is an example:

```
try
{
  String schmarr;
  ... blah
  return;
  System.out.println("OMG!  Schmarr: " + schmarr); // This is unreachable.
}
finally
{
  System.out.println("Not so OMG.  code in a finally will execute");
}
```

Comment: Yes guys tats correct but the reason for this question is i so such a code when i view a class file using the jd-gui(Tool to Convert .class files to .java files).

Comment: you are not seeing what you think you are seeing.  In my, limited, experience, java decompilers dont seem to handle try catch blocks very well (this includes finally blocks).  If you decompiled code and see what you describe in your question, then it seems likely that the code "after" the return is in either a catch or a finally block.

Comment: yes DwB wat you have told is some what correct i converted the same .class file with another decompiler and found the **else** statement and the adjacent lines are wrapped by a while(true) followed by a return statements. Thanks Guys..

Answer (score 1):

No, the `return` statement will give back control back to the calling method.

Many IDEs will flag the `Toast` as unreachable statement.